spark filter timestamp column takes too much time
i want to filter timestamp column from jdbc source (Oracle) which has about 4,000,000,000 rows
when i write sql query it returns the result fast , but as i use spark native filter it takes too much time (more than 45mins)
i check to use push-down predicate to databse and the physical plan prove it too:

in my sql query i use to_date function and it is fast , but i think in this way it use something else like to_timestamp
in addition i use 10 partitions to read from jdbc
here is my code:
val filteredMsat = msat.select(col("TRANSACTION_DATE"),col("ID"))
      .filter(col("TRANSACTION_DATE").isNotNull)
      .filter(to_date(col("TRANSACTION_DATE")) >= to_date(lit("2023-12-01"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
      .filter(to_date(col("TRANSACTION_DATE")) < to_date(lit("2023-12-02"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

i want to use spark with out implicit sql query with good performane

can you please clarify if you mean using "spark.sql" for sql query or by using the jdbc driver directly?

it may happen that when you run query manually in oracle it by default limit output, e.g. returns first 500 rows. But when you run it via spark it loads everything to spark from your db.

@Grish I want to fetch all rows , I check that the push down  predicate is on but it takes too much time to return values , however if i run them in oracle directly i get rows very fast

@Chris I have to options, first use spark.sql and write sql in spark , the second way is to use spark dataframe API , in spark.sql it reurns all desired rows fast but with dataframe API no

ah, can you then please show the sql used when calling spark.sql?  Both should be identical but there are some edge cases
